# How to make the letters upper case

Tags: python

The point of this is to get the user to type their name and once it prints to only have their initials print out in capital letters. How can I get the first letter of each name the user types (assuming the user only types first name and last name). This is what I have so far, any help is welcome. Right now this code will only print the first two letters of the name they type as capital but I cannot figure out how to print initials only in capital letters

```
name=input("what is your full name")
list=[]
list=name.split()
sname=""
for i in range(len(list)-1):
    s=list[i]
    sname=sname+s[0].upper()
    sname=sname+s[1].upper()
print(sname)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a relatively straightforward approach - no need for loops:

```
name=input("what is your full name")
lst=name.split()
print(lst[0][0].upper(),lst[-1][0].upper())
```

The user's input is split into items within a list. The first element of both the first and last items are then printed as capitalized characters.

Answer (score 0):

Simple method to do so:

```
s = input().split()
ans = s[0].upper()+ " " + s[-1].upper()
print(ans)
```

Comment: so this just capitalizes the first letter in each name they type, i want only their initials to print and they need to be in capital letters

Answer (score 0):

To print out the initials in capital letter use the following code:

```py
names = input("What is your name? ").split()
initials = "".join([name[0] for name in names])
print(initials.upper())
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming people only type in first name and last name, the following code should work:

```
#perm.py
name = input("what is your full name: ")

for i in name.split():
  print(i.title()[:1], end=' ')
```

Result:

```
D:\Python> python perm.py
what is your full name: Henry Tjhia
H T
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
def get_initials():
    entry = input("What is your full name?")
    return list(map(lambda name: name[0].upper(), filter(bool, entry.split(" "))))

initials = get_initials()
print("".join(initials))
```

Comment: that would work however i haven't used lambda before or .join

Comment: Oh yea I went a while without using them but they are awesome to clean up your code and get around big for loops.